# Redirect to an Android App if installed else go to the webapp

Tags: android, web, web-applications

I have to integrate my Android App with another 3rd party App. So, we can't make changes to that 3rd party android app. We have provided them a link with a web URL which will be clicked by the users.

Now, on opening of that URL in a browser, we will have to do the following things :

1. If our Android App is installed, then open the our Android App.
2. If our Android App is NOT installed, the open the corresponding page in our web-app.

I am not sure how to check if our App is installed on that phone from browser itself.

Kindly help me out how to go about it. I have gone through few similar questions but they all suggest to make changes in that 3rd party App which is not the case with me here.

Comment: Maybe. But then how to go about it ? We need to open that link in Android App if it is installed else go to the web app link.

Comment: what the 3rd party app doing in this case? isn't it the deep linking redirection that you talking about? as far as i understood your question, you just want to click a link open your app and if app not available then open web page. what role 3rd party app playing here?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want. The 3rd party app opens our link in the browser. And then from browser we have redirect it to the app if installed otherwise open the webpage. The role of 3rd party is just to open the link in a browser and it is out of bounds for us.
Is deeplinking redirection the way to go about it ? Is there anything relevant document you can guide me to ?

Comment: you can use deep linking for it

Comment: @VaibhavPachauri here is the vary nice example from google, please check it's really easy to achieve your goal  https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking